# Laravel 8 どちらのSQLクエリのほうが良いですか？

Tags: sql, laravel

2つのテーブルがあります。
**① Articles（記事）**
ユーザが投稿した記事一覧
**② Favorites（お気に入り）**
ユーザがお気に入りに登録した記事一覧

① には記事とその情報が登録されています。
② はお気に入りに登録された記事のid （① の主キー）とユーザIDを列に持ちます。

お気に入り一覧を抽出するとき、以下の2つの方法のうちどちらを選択するか迷っています。

**A案**
②から該当ユーザが登録した記事ID を取得。
その後、そのID を条件に①から記事一覧を取得する。

```
$article_ids = Favorite::where('user_id', $user_id)->pluck('article_id');
$articles = Article::whereIn('id', $article_ids)->get();
```

**B案**
ユーザIDを条件に、①と②を記事ID で結合して記事一覧を取得する。

```
$articles = Favorite::leftJoin('articles', 'favorites.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
->where('favorites.user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

**気にしているのは以下です。**
(1) このような場合、A、Bどちらの方法がオーソドックスか？
(2) パフォーマンスに優れるのはどちらか？
Aは内部的にSQLを2つ発行している。
Bはコストの高い結合という処理を行っている。
(3) 総合的にどちらの方法が優れているか。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: パフォーマンスという視点では、実際の環境で試した結果を元に判断した方が良さそうです。

Answer (score 1):

勝手に微調整を加えます。また IDE と相性がいい・インデントが揃えやすいように `::query()` から入ります。

```php
// A: WHERE IN (1, 2, 3, ...) で連続的に SQL を 2 つ発行
$article_ids = Favorite::query()
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->pluck('article_id');
$articles = Article::query()
    ->find($article_ids);

// B: JOIN を使う
$articles = Article::query()
    ->leftJoin('favorites', 'favorites.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
    ->where('favorites.user_id', $user_id)
    ->select('articles.*')
    ->get();

// C: WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ...) を使う相関サブクエリ
$articles = Article::query()
    ->whereHas('favorites', function (Builder $query) use ($user_id){
        $query->where('user_id' => $user_id);
    })
    ->get();

// D: WHERE IN (SELECT ...) を使う非相関サブクエリ
// https://github.com/mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery
$articles = Article::query()
    ->hasByNonDependentSubquery('favorites', function (Builder $query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('user_id' => $user_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

#### A

最も素朴なコードですが，ページネーションを入れようとすると少し考えることが増えます。また `articles` テーブルにしかない情報でページネーションは困難です。それゆえ，使用できるケースは限られます。

#### B

**パフォーマンス的に最も優れる**コードですが，地雷が非常に多い使い方です。以下の点に注意してください。熟練者以外はあまり使わないほうがいい方法です。

- 適用できるケースが限られます。`HasMany` リレーションに対して使うと，**同じIDのレコードが重複して出現する**リスクがあります。「同じユーザは1個しか同じ記事をいいねできない」という制約があり，かつ単一の `user_id` で絞り込む場合は問題ありません。また `HasOne` `BelongsTo` に対して使う場合は全く問題ありません。
- **`->select('articles.*')`** を付与するのを忘れないように。これがないと `favorites` のフィールドが紛れ込んで悲惨なバグを生むことに繋がります。
- `Article::query()` から始めてください。`Favorite::query()` からだと，取得結果が `Favorite` のインスタンスになってしまいます。

#### C

おそらく**最もオーソドックスな**な方法です。いろいろな場合において使え，安全性の高い方法ですが，**クエリオプティマイザが賢くない MySQL だと露骨にパフォーマンスが落ちます**。PostgreSQL の場合は問題ありません。

#### D

MySQL で C の問題点を解消するために自作したライブラリを使ったコードです。オーソドックスという観点ではマイナスですが，使いやすさと高パフォーマンスを両立しています。

- [mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery: Convert has() and whereHas() constraints to non-dependent subqueries.](https://github.com/mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery)